# Some error about cursor in Pl/pgsql

Tags: postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

**I know the right way to insert value from a table:

`insert into city (pop) select pop+2 from city`

 I just want to know how cursor works in Pl/pgsql .**
I wish to use cursor in loop to insert some value:

```
create or replace function test(  ) returns void as 
$$
declare
cur cursor for select pop+2 from city order by pop;
b int;
row record;
begin
for row in cur
LOOP 
fetch cur into b;
insert into city(pop) select b;
end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

However, when I type `select test()`  and the result table is:

[image]

It's very strange that only two rows are inserted. So I want to know what lead to this result?

**Update my question in 04/05/2016:**
I revise the function like this:

```
create or replace function test(  ) returns void as 
$$
declare
cur cursor for select * from city order by pop;
b record;
begin
for b in cur
LOOP 
insert into city(pop) select b.pop+2;
RAISE NOTICE ' % IS INSERTED' , b;
end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

Then I get the correct result:
[image]

But I still wonder why in the first function, only two rows are inserted.

Comment: Why are you using a (slow and inefficient) cursor for this in the first place? You can do this **much** more efficiently using a single statement: `insert into city (pop) select pop+2 from city;`.

Comment: Just a guess: there are two fetches in the your loop: first, implicit, at `for row in cur LOOP` and second, explicit, at `fetch cur into b;`. So at each iteration you are doing actually two fetches.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure out that why the result is wrong, just like **Abelisto's comment**  . I did two fetchers in  `loop` at each step:

1. at `for row in cur LOOP` ,
2. at `fetch cur into b`

So the first row `where pop=500` and the third row where `pop =1000` have already been fetched in `for loop`, and it can't be fetched by `b`.